# apache 403 forbidden error when adding an alias, windows

Tags: windows-server-2008, apache-2.4

I'm looking to add a alias to "C:/Apache24/static" in Apache, simple enough, right?

```
Alias /static "C:/Apache24/static" 

<Directory "C:/Apache24/static">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I cant seem to see what i am doing wrong. here is a copy of my config

http://pastebin.com/0rJwuPB4

Comment: Please include any relevant sections of your Apache config in the question, so we don't have to read through hundreds of lines of comments, and also your question will still be useful after the pastebin goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reviewing your `httpd.conf`, I'd recommend you going over following document:
[Upgrading to 2.4 from 2.2 - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html) *AND* posting part of your `error_log` so it can be future troubleshoot, as for alias itself, your syntax seems correct.

Comment: accidentally you showed me the answer, using the upgrading document i noticed the way that access control was changed, once i changed lines 278 and 289 to Require all granted. it worked